# LAMP error: session_start() failed: No space left on device (28), but

Tags: php, linux, apache, lamp

Ubuntu server 10.04, Apache 2.2.14, PHP 5.3.2, MySQL.
For the drive where session files are stored:

df -h:

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/md1              450G   86G  341G  21% /
```

df -ih:

```
Filesystem            Inodes   IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/md1                116M    9.4M    107M    9% /
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe your Apache user has a quota?

Comment: Good idea, but quotas are not enabled.

Comment: Strange. Can you verify in php.ini where sessions are being saved? (As @alsotoes suggests below)

Comment: Verified.  There's only one volume, and it's not full.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally remembered to answer with the solution! Turns out there were too many files in one directory. Had to start hashing the session files into subdirectories.

Comment: Hmm, do you happen to have any pointers/guides on how you went about that? I think I may have hit the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Apache reports this error when it can't register a lock on a file(which it assumes is because the fs is full). Next time it occurs try running

```
ipcs -s
```

and look for an abundance of registered locks owned by the apache process. You can then either remove them with ipcrm, or raise their limit with the kernel variable (kernel.sem) as mentioned [In this blog post](http://www.justin.my/2010/03/solved-error-28-no-space-left-on-device-mod_python-failed-to-create-global-mutex-2-of-8-tmpmpmtx142352/).

Answer (score 0):

just check in the php.ini file where the sessions file are stored, and then check the free space, if is 100% used, change the fstab configuration (in case of a (re)mounted directory) and restart the server, or change the path and restart the apache server.

In my case:

```
evo ~ # locate php.ini
/etc/php/apache2-php5/php.ini
/etc/php/cli-php5/php.ini

evo ~ # grep -v ";" /etc/php/apache2-php5/php.ini | grep session | grep path
session.save_path = "/tmp"
session.cookie_path = /

evo ~ # grep -v ";" /etc/php/cli-php5/php.ini | grep session | grep path
session.save_path = "/tmp"
session.cookie_path = /

evo ~ # df -ha /tmp   
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root             230G   27G  203G  12% /

evo ~ # df -ha / 
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root             230G   27G  203G  12% /
```

Comment: Yeah, got that suggestion from the Google also, and that's why I posted the output of df -h.  To be clear, that's /dev/md1 is the volume on which the session files are stored.  So, full drive is not the issue.  Nor is it out of iNotes.  Any other ideas?